# Gallery HTML images show a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-gallery

First of all I want say sorry for my bad english and I will try my best to get help and help you help me out.

Well i have a project for my web designer class and my teacher wants me to do a gallery html page but I could not find any answer or anything close to what I am looking for.

Well i will explain how he wants...

Let's imagine a gallery page with 3 thumbnail photos.
Then the first thumbnail it's an airplane, the second it's a boat, the third it's a car.

Now if I click on the Airplane thumbnail it should only display slideshow of Airplanes and if I click on the Car Thumbnail it should only display Car images in the slideshow ... Did anybody understood what i meant? please if not i will explain it better.
Thank you so much, and again please sorry for my bad english and explanation.

This is what i currently have from now but when I click on the first image it opens the one I click and when I click next go to the next one on the side of it
[image]

Comment: could you please show us what you've already tried?

Comment: @MaxLangerak i edited my post please take a look at it... sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a carousel? When you click on a thumbnail do you want a popover to appear and have carousel characteristics? To navigate from one picture to another.

If it's possible could you show your code in jsfiddle.net please?

Comment: no i want to click on the airplane image and it will open on a pop up gallery that will only show airplanes imagens even if there are a thumbnail of a car or of a boat thumbnail that's what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the slideshow function looks a bit like this:

```
function slideShow() {
    var slideShowImages = new Array();

    slideShow.prototype.load = function(img){ /*loads img into array*/ };
    slideShow.prototype.start = function(){ /*starts the slideshow*/ };
    slideShow.prototype.stop = function() { /*stops slideshow*/ };
    slideShow.prototype.empty = function() { /*empties array*/ };
};
```

To make sure you only show the images of a certain vehicle place them in an array:

```
var airplanes = new Array();
var cars = new Array();
var boats = new Array();
```

Then when loading all images, place them in the right array:

```
var boatImg = new Image();
boatImg.src = theSourceOfImage;
boatImg.addEventListener('load', function() { boats.push(boatImg) }); 
//etc etc.
```

Attach a click handler to the thumbnails.

```
SlideShow = new slideShow();

$("#boatThumbNailId").click(function() { 
   //now place all of the pictures from the boat array in the slideshow
   for(var i = 0; i < boats.length; i++)
       SlideShow.load(boats[i]);
   //then just start the slideShow
   SlideShow.start();
});
```

I hope this will be of some help to you, good luck.

Comment: yes yes it's something like this but i never seen this before could you help me out on my project? do you have email, facebook, skype or something so we can get in touch?

Comment: Send me an email, and I will see what I can do, my email is on my page.

Comment: i can't find your email on your page sorry

Comment: you there? i can't find you email on your page please help me